# スクリプトの承認が切れ、設定したトリガーが走らず、Googleからエラー通知が来るようになった

Tags: google-apps-script

GASでスプレッドシートに設定したトリガーでスクリプトを起動させているが（フォーム送信及び時間帯設定トリガー）
このところ、承認が無いからエラーになったとの旨のメール通知が来るようになった。
スクリプトの内容は変更しておらず　しばらくの間安定して稼働していた。
大量のプロジェクトがあり、毎回このエラーのたびに手作業で再承認しているが、これは定期的に再承認を求められるものなのでしょうか？
回避する方法は無いのでしょうか？

以下の記事を参考にし、Developer HubでON の設定もしています。
しかし相変わらずエラー通知が来ます。
（１つのプロジェクトに対し対応後にそれが来たかはわかりません。
まっだ一度も対処していないものかもしれませんが）

[GASで「その操作を実行するには承認が必要です」が再び出るエラー](https://officeforest.org/wp/info/gas%e3%81%a7%e3%80%8c%e3%81%9d%e3%81%ae%e6%93%8d%e4%bd%9c%e3%82%92%e5%ae%9f%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%81%ab%e3%81%af%e6%89%bf%e8%aa%8d%e3%81%8c%e5%bf%85%e8%a6%81%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99%e3%80%8d/)

Googleに問合せしましたがサポート外と言われこちらを紹介されました。

数百のプロジェクトがあり毎回これでは対応に限界があるので困っています。